# Yolo version without Data Augmentation

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, yolo

I am trying to run yolov5 for an object detection problem. Yolov5 has inbuilt data augmentation which is defined in the cfg.yaml file. I commented the image augmentation hyperpameters but ran into errors with the mosaic parameter.

**Is there any other way to run yolo models without data augmentation? If yes, could you share any article, blog, github repo, stackoverflow solution or youtube video for reference.**

*I am trying to find out the impact of data augmentation in YOLO models. So I want to run the same YOLO model with and without data augmentation.*

Criteria:

1. Model should be run on tensorflow 2.0 and above. Certain yolo models don't pass this criteria.
2. YOLO models above yolov3.

Please let me know if more information is needed to understand the problem.